# NodeJS taking long time to response

Tags: node.js, pm2

My NodeJS application is taking very long time to response and when i monitor it through PM2 it shows below

```
Heap Size                                  44.42 MiB  
│ Heap Usage                                   78.36 %
│ Used Heap Size                             34.81 MiB
│ Active requests                                    0
│ Active handles                                    10
│ Event Loop Latency                           0.23 ms                                                      
│ Event Loop Latency p95                       1.07 ms
│ HTTP Mean Latency                             418 ms
│ HTTP P95 Latency                           4595.2 ms
│ HTTP                                    3.55 req/min
```

I noticed my HTTP p95 Latency is very high which usually should be under 500ms, let me know what i can do to improve it.

Comment: A part of your code could be helpful. The above statistics are important but we should know what the is doing in those 5 seconds.

Comment: This could basically be anything .. Some application and environment details would be much appreciated.